# BASH script with a $ not saving correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have a bash script, which I run doing the following `sudo ./test`

The bash script needs to create a repo, and save the following data in it.

So, this is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Inputing data... " 
echo "[mongodb-org-3.2]
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
```

However, because the releasever has a $ in front of it, the script save the text like this:

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
```

Instead of like this:

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$c/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
```

Any idea how I can treat the `$releasever` as text rather than a variable?

I tried putting double quotes around it however that still does not work. I am new to bash scripting so any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent variable expansion.

Using double quotes:

```
sh-4.1$ baseurl1="https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/"
sh-4.1$ echo $baseurl1
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
```

Using single quotes:

```
sh-4.1$ baseurl2='https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/'
sh-4.1$ echo $baseurl2
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the back-slash character to indicate that you don't want to call a bash variable, e.g.:

```
echo \$HELLO
```